# MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS Warning On my IIS Server Failed Trace Log

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis, hosting

I created Web service with multiple endpoints. And I hosted that in my public iis server.

My client trying to hit my end points, Except One endpoint rest of the end point are working fine.

I can hit that particular endpoint with soap UI. But I couldn't hit with their application. Using failed request tracing option I noticed a following warning

> ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="500", HttpReason="Internal Server Error", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.  (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""

Please help me to find out this problem. Issues on my side ??

Comment: This means there is an unhanded exception with in the code. Does your service works correctly in visual studio ?

Comment: yes. Its working fine with my visual studio. I can hit that particular end point with SOAP UI and Curl command. But we can't do that in third party application.

Comment: @RaviA. This means there is an unhanded exception with in the code ? And not logging in Event Viewer, IIS Logs, Failed Tracing Web, WCF Tracing... ? not log error in anyway ?

Comment: There should be error logged by. Net framework in event viewer with call stack.

Comment: @RaviA. Not logged for Behaviour Extensions WCF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229490/iis-500-error-wcf-service-and-failed-request-tracing-not-info?noredirect=1#comment89470356_51229490